# Can the limit at an essential singularity be infinite from all directions?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

Suppose a function $f$ is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that for all fixed $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{r \to 0} |f(re^{i\theta})|=\infty$. Does it necessarily follow that $f$ has a pole at $z_0$? Or is it possible for the singularity to be essential?

(Recall that if $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)|=\infty$, then $f$ must have a pole. But I'm requiring only the limit from any fixed direction to be infinite.)

If the latter, this should be one of those funny counterexamples in analysis. On the other hand, the compactness of $S^1$ vaguely suggests to me that it has to be a pole.

Comment: $e^{1\over z}$?

Comment: @user619894 $e^{1/z} \to 0$ as $|z| \to 0$ along $arg (z)=\pi$.

Comment: I don't really know, I would just speculate that something like $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^4}+\frac{1}{8!z^8}+\ldots$$ _might_ work. It definitely converges in $|z|>0$ and it definitely tends to $\infty$ alongside $z=re^{i\theta}$ as $r\to 0^+$, where $\theta$ is of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}\pi$ and maybe this can even be extended to any $\theta$??! Or I may be completely wrong.

Comment: The answer is yes - there are entire nonconstant functions $g$ st for any $\theta$ we have $g(re^{i\theta})\to 0, r \to \infty$; take $f(z)=1/g(1/z)$

Comment: @Conrad What would be a good example? Genuinely curious (as I suppose the OP is too).

Comment: @Stinking Let $h_1(z)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{zt}}{t^t}dt$; note that the integral is convergent at $0$ (continuous) and at infinity due to the super-exponential denominator, so $h_1$ entire; with Cauchy applied carefully, one can show that for $|\Im z| \ge \pi/2+1, |h_1(z)| \le K$ so $h_1$ is bounded outside of a strip around the reals; $h(z)=h_1(z-i(\pi+3)/2)$ is bounded outside of a horizontal strip above the reals, so $h$ is bounded on any line through the origin as any such intersects the strip in a segment; then $g(z)=\frac{h(z)-h(0)}{z}$ goes to zero at infinity on any ray through zero

Comment: @Stinking And as for details about $h_1$, one notes that the integrand is also analytic in $t$ outside the negative reals with the usual $t^t=e^{t \log t}$ for the principal log, so (for $\Im z >0$) one uses Cauchy on the standard first quadrant contour in $t$ (2 segments and two quarter circles) $\epsilon \to R \to iR \to i\epsilon \to \epsilon$ to estimate the integral with the condition on the imaginary part of $z$ coming from the imaginary segment $iR \to i\epsilon$ part and then one lets $\epsilon \to 0, R \to \infty$